# SP2010 Workflow not starting with custom code

Tags: workflow

Am using workflow from SPD2010 attached in item creation. Its working perfectly through OOB new form. In contrast, its not firing when the item was created through custom code and there is no workflow running in the list item. Any idea?

TIA.